# Subcomponents dagger2 implementation

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvp, dagger-2

i'm trying to apply MVP concepts using dagger2 following [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger/) Google repo on Github
i have multiple fragments splash screen i have created the first splash screen fragment using MVP

and there is it's component class

```
@AScoped
@Component(dependencies = DataRepoComponent.class,modules = SplashScreenModule.class)
public interface SplashScreenComponent {
    void inject(SplashScreenActivity splashScreenActivity);
}
```

this component class depends on a data provider component called DataRepoComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {DataRepoModule.class, ApplicationModule.class})
public interface DataRepoComponent {
    DataRepo getDataRepo();
}
```

and following is the data repo module

```
@Module
public class DataRepoModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    OperatorHelper provideSharedPreferncesHelper(Context context){
        return new OperatorHelper(context);
    }


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    SharedPreferences provideSharedPreference(Context context){
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }
}
```

and everything works just fine till this when i try to add anther splash screen fragment lets call it FirstSplashScreenFragment
when i add it's component like this

```
@AScoped
@Component(dependencies = DataRepoComponent.class, modules = FirstSplashScreenModule.class)
public interface FirstSplashScreenComponent {
    void inject(SplashScreenActivity splashScreenActivity);

}
```

i get the following errors
1 -

> Error:(5, 49) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerDataRepoComponent
>
> cannot be provided without @Proides-annotated method

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, It's really hard to find out your problem because some pieces of your puzzle is missing, but I guess this might help:

add this to your DataRepoComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
DataRepo provideDataRepo(){
    return new DataRepo();
}
```

by the way, I think looking at this sample repo could help you get more familiar with dagger:

> http://github.com/mmirhoseini/fyber_mobile_offers